# admin/content/file missing

Tags: 7, views, files

I have some problems with files. Everyone is talking about admin/content/file, but I just don't have the link under /admin/content, and going to the url by hand returns me to admin/content.

I seem to be pretty much up to date (drupal 7.50, file_entity 7.x-1.5) and media is working (it's just buggy in strange ways).

Where should I look to find why the link is not showing under /admin/content ? Iow, who should be providing the view ? That would give me a clue.

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared Drupal Cache and checked File Entity user permission if they are set to right roles.?

Comment: Yes cache. There is no 'permissions' link next to the module in /admin/modules, and File Entity has no specific box of settings under /people/permissions (should it?). Clicking on 'configure' for the module takes me to /admin/config/media/file-types.

Comment: Hmmm .. File Entity seems to be part of the 7.x-1.x branch of Media. I would prefer not to update to the 7.x-2.x branch just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install and enable the File Entity (fieldable files) module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity

7.x-2.12 works flawlessly.